# Number of integer solutions with hard restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

In the jungle of posts on *math.stackexachange* related to this subject I have been searching quite a while now. I read some very useful posts however I can't solve my own problem. My version of *the number of integer solutions* sounds like this:

**Question**:
Let $x + y + z \leq 13$ with the following restrictions: $x \leq y \leq x+2$ and $x \leq z$. Find the number of possibilities using a generating function.

Related to this problem I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405046/counting-number-of-solutions-with-restrictions). I tried so for the equation $x + y + z =13$:

Say $z=x+z'$, $x+2=y+x'$ and $y=x+y'$. However replacing those expressions into the equation, I got stuck  with replacing $x'$ and $y'$ for $x$ and $y$. The only thing I see is that: $x' + y'=2$. How can I use this technique properly?

And what about the inequality? How to deal with $x + y + z \leq 13$? Thanx in advance!

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ non-negative integers?

Comment: We deal with the inequality part only, in order to mention  useful trick. The number of solutions in non-negative integers of $x_1+\cdots +x_n\le k$ is equal to the number of solutions in non-negative integers of $x_1+\cdots +x_n+x_{n+1}=k$.

Comment: Yes of course! I forgot to mention this, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, the inequalities are essentially just saying that $y=x+y', x+2=y+x', z=x+z'$ for some non-negative integers $x',y',z'\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$. Then:

$$3x+y'+z'\le 13\iff 3x+y'+z'+A=13$$

for some non-negative integer $A$.

But we still haven't used $x+2=y+x'\iff x'+y'=2$ (we used $y=x+y'$), which is just saying that $y'\in[0;2]$.

Thus the generating function we need is:

$$(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12})(1+x+x^2)(\sum_{i=0}^{13} x^i)(\sum_{i=0}^{13} x^i)$$

The coefficient of $x^{13}$ will be our answer. [It is 105](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E12%29%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%28sum+x%5Ei%2C+i%3D0..13%29%5E2).
For a way of finding the coefficient of generating functions see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/908949/107671).

Since $(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+x^{12})(1+x+x^2)=(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{14})$, we can simply write our generating function as:

$$\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i\right)^3\right]_{x^{13}}=\left[\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\right]_{x^{13}}=\binom{13+3-1}{13}=\binom{15}{13}=\binom{15}{2}=\frac{15\cdot 14}{2}=15\cdot 7=105$$